# Ошибки сканирования в Google Webmasters

Tags: url, google-webmasters

1. подобные ошибки сканирования влияют на позиции сайта в поиске?
2. как исправить эти заранее проиндексированные страницы, чтобы гугл вебмастер не выводил эти сообщения. Сейчас действительно на сайте этих страниц уже не существует. Сделать по всем просто 301 редирект на другие страницы?

> 1             url   coupon-categories/mens-footwear/       код ответа 
>   404
>
> 2             url   coupon-categories/electronics/         код ответа 
>   404

Answer (score 1):

1) Влияют, Google этого не любит и опускает сайт в выдаче.

2) Надо просто запустить переиндексацию сайта в Webmasters.